# Activerecord syntax of where clause on joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to select all Line items that have an order that has been created between two dates (order has the column date)

Here's what im trying to do

```
LineItem.where(:product_id => self.id).joins(:order).where(:orders => {"date > ? and date < ?", date_start, date_end}).all
```

I cant figure out the syntax of the last condition...
I know this kind of where do work:

```
.where("date > ? and date < ?", date_start, date_end)
```

and this kind of where too:

```
.where(:orders => {:id => 23043})
```

but how can i do a mix of the two kinds so i can get something like the first request?

Comment: It `{"date > ? and date < ?", date_start, date_end}` should give *syntax error*.. Is it running ?

Comment: Ahh! you are looking something like that.. I got shocked.. :-)

Comment: Yes lol. I really don't know how I should syntax it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
.where(:date => date_start..date_end, :order => {:id => 23043})
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain the clauses together and it will automatically join them with an AND:

```
.where("date > ? and date < ?", date_start, date_end). 
  where(:orders => {:id => 23043})
```

Comment: I dont want to chain. I want to do something like the first request i posted. I just want to mix the two "kind" of clause together so that I can get all line_items that have an order that has been created between two dates.

Comment: @zoum26 You cannot mix those two argument types in one call, it’s just not supported, plain and simple. Chaining is how this is done.

Comment: ok but how can i get what i want? I'm new to activerecord...in sql i would have done something like this: 
`Select *
from line_item
join order
on line_item.order_id = order.id
where order.date between date_start and date_end`